# Standard method to unsubscribe from an event in a user control

Tags: c#-4.0, idisposable, windows-forms-designer

I have a user control that is listening to an event.

```
public partial class ObserverControl : UserControl
{
    public ObserverControl()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        Observatory.DataUpdated += OnDataUpdate;
    }

    private void OnDataUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Process new data
    }
}
```

What is the best way to ensure that when this UserControl is closed, it unsubscribes from the event?  Currently, it closes the Observatory class is still trying to send updates to the ObserverControl.

I have considered using IDisposable, but I'm not exactly sure how it would work (especially since the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method is already overridden in the designer code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the dispose method out of the generated file and add

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            Observatory.DataUpdated -= OnDataUpdate;

        }
```

Comment: I would really like to not mess with the designer file if possible - I try to avoid it at all costs.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: If you move it out of the designer file and into your code file it won't get overwritten.  I believe this is your best option.

Comment: Here is another option http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/10/howtodisposemembersfromforms.aspx personally I would prefer to move the dispose method into my code file